# How can i join Master-Detail-Detail Tables with Linq in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 table
a,b and c

```
a.Id,a.code /master
b.Id.b.code,b.aId,c.Id /detail
c.Id,c.code / detail of detail
```

i will join this three table with linq and show it in grid. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from recordA in context.TableA
            join recordB in context.TableB
            on recordA.Id equals recordB.aId
            join recordC in context.TableC
            on recordB.cId equals recordC.Id
            select new 
            {
               // whatever columns are appropriate
            };
```

Comment: how can i write this query with lambda expression ?

Comment: @drorhan, `.Join` is kind of ugly when represented in lambda syntax. If I have a moment, I'll come back and add in an example. But for now, I encourage you to download Linqpad. You can type query expressions and see the results in Lambda syntax, as well as SQL (if applicable) and IL.